# Running ng lint --fix does absolutely nothing

Tags: typescript, angular-cli, config, tslint

I essentially updated `npm` and the angular cli `ng` to their latest versions and created a fresh angular project by running: `ng new app-name-here --routing`

The first thing I wanted to do was to change the indentation of the project from 2 spaces to 4 spaces so I went ahead to the `tsconfig.json` file and changed:

```json
...
"indent": {
    "options": [
         "spaces"
     ]
}
...
```

to the following as per [this](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/indent/).

```json
...
"indent": {
    "options": [
         "spaces", 4
     ]
}
...
```

Ran `ng lint --fix` again and it says all files pass lint.

I was weirded out because the schema specified by the resource I linked to it has the format of an object instead of an array. So I changed to that instead, retried and no luck.

How may I lint my angular project with 4 spaces instead of 2?

**Note** Just tried changing "spaces" to "tabs" and the linter showed warnings. But I just can't get to set the amount of spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've [opened an issue on github to the angular cli project](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/19208) and the response was that this was a bug in the `tslint` project.

I've changed my configuration so my linter is now `eslint` and updated the angular scripts accordingly. Now it just works.